# Cannot configure ETH1 on centos 6

Tags: networking, centos

I have a server running Centos 6.4. eth0 is configured and works fine with an internet (external to my LAN) address. I am attempting to configure eth1 with the following ifcfg-eth1 file:

```
DEVICE=eth1
HWADDR=A4:BA:DB:14:E3:B8
TYPE=Ethernet
ONBOOT=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=no
BOOTPROTO=static
ipaddr=192.168.1.210
gateway=192.168.1.1
dns1=8.8.8.8
```

After I do an IFUP ETH1 command, I get an entry for it but no IPV4 address as shown in the following ifconfig output:

```
eth0 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr A4:BA:DB:14:E3:B7 
inet addr:xxx.xxx.xxx.131 Bcast:xxx.xxx.xxx.143 Mask:255.255.255.240
inet6 addr: fe80::a6ba:dbff:fe14:e3b7/64 Scope:Link
UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
RX packets:588 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:133 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
RX bytes:55844 (54.5 KiB) TX bytes:15469 (15.1 KiB)
Interrupt:16 

eth1 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr A4:BA:DB:14:E3:B8 
inet6 addr: fe80::a6ba:dbff:fe14:e3b8/64 Scope:Link
UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
RX packets:135 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:6 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
RX bytes:8640 (8.4 KiB) TX bytes:492 (492.0 b)
Interrupt:17
```

I have rebooted since the change just to be on the safe side. The ip4 address it seems to default to is: 10.170.16.1. If I ping 10.170.16.1 the output is:

```
PING 10.170.16.1 (10.170.16.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.170.16.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=254 time=7.69 ms
64 bytes from 10.170.16.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=254 time=6.31 ms
64 bytes from 10.170.16.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=254 time=6.88 ms
64 bytes from 10.170.16.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=254 time=7.15 ms
^C
```

Network manager is not running.

Help!

Thanks

Comment: Entry capitalization matters in the ifcfg-eth* files.

Comment: @EtanReisner That was it. I had forgotten that. That did the trick. Make it a real answer and I'll accept it. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Entry capitalization matters in the ifcfg-eth* files.

Those files are read into a shell script context and looked up by known name and `ipaddr` is not the same variable as `IPADDR`.